# add <hr> in php file on joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have this:

```
if ($copy_email_activated == true && !empty($data['contact_email_copy']))
            {
                $copytext    = JText::sprintf('COM_CONTACT_COPYTEXT_OF', $contact->name, $sitename);
                $copytext    .= "\r\n\r\n" . $body;
                $copysubject = JText::sprintf('COM_CONTACT_COPYSUBJECT_OF', $subject);

                $mail = JFactory::getMailer();
                $mail->addRecipient($email);
                $mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
                $mail->setSender(array($mailfrom, $fromname));
                $mail->setSubject($copysubject);
                $mail->setBody($copytext);
                $sent = $mail->Send();
            }
```

And I need add in the body, one tag `<hr>`, but not working . `<hr>` or echo `<hr>`.
Any solutions?

Comment: try : $mail->setBody($copytext . "<hr>");

Comment: Thans Anders, but not work! The HTML tag still appears

Comment: Sry did just fast read. This works for me: $copytext   = "\r\n\r\n" . $body . "<hr>";

Comment: Thanks, I was able to fix it!!

Answer (score 1):

I need to tell the mailer it is HTML. This is done with isHTML.
$mail->IsHTML(true);

Then .'

---

' and it works properly.